# How does one reduce a list of boolean values in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, apply, reduce

Given a list of values, I want to reduce the list to T if all the elements are not NIL, NIL if not. This gives me an error:

```
(apply #'and (get-some-list))
```

As does this:

```
(reduce #'and (get-some-list))
```

This is the best I've come up with:

```
[11]> (defun my-and (x y) (and x y))
MY-AND

[12]> (reduce #'my-and '(T T T T T))
T

[13]> (reduce #'my-and '(T T T T NIL))
NIL
```

Why is "#'and" invalid? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#'and` is invalid because `and` is a macro, not a function.

You can get around having to define a named function, by using a lambda:

```
(reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y)) (get-some-list) :initial-value t)
```

There's no shortcut like `#'` though.

Alternatively you can also use `every` with the identify function as the predicate.

Comment: Actually @PietroBraione you are the one who is **wrong** :D. If you provide the `:initial-value` flag then it will not be called with one argument. This is made explicit in the hyperspec: "If the subsequence is empty and no initial-value is given, then the function is called with zero arguments, and reduce returns whatever function does. This is the only case where the function is called with other than two arguments. "

Answer (score 21):

You can use the EVERY function:

```
(every #'identity '(T T T T T))  ->  T
```

and

```
(every #'identity '(T T T T NIL))  ->  NIL
```

Probably the most efficient way is using LOOP:

```
(loop for element in '(T T T T nil) always element)  ->  NIL
```

The advantage is that no function calls over the list elements are needed.

`#'` is a read macro that expands into FUNCTION during read the expression. So `#'and` is (FUNCTION AND).

FUNCTION is described here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm

FUNCTION takes a function name or a lambda expression and returns the corresponding function object.

AND is defined here:  http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_and.htm

It says that AND is a macro, not a function. The consequence is that (FUNCTION AND) does not work, since FUNCTION needs a function and not a macro to return the corresponding function object. As sepp2k describes in his answer, you can create a function using LAMBDA and use the macro AND inside that function. Macros cannot be passed as values and later be called via FUNCALL or APPLY. This works only with functions.

This solution is written as

```
(reduce (lambda (x y) (and x y)) (get-some-list))
```

LAMBDA is a macro that expands `(lambda (...) ...)` into  `(function (lambda (...) ...))`.

So above is really:

```
(reduce (function (lambda (x y) (and x y))) (get-some-list))
```

which can be written as

```
(reduce #'(lambda (x y) (and x y)) (get-some-list))
```

FUNCTION is needed because Common Lisp makes a difference between the namespace for values and functions. REDUCE needs to get the function passed as an argument by value. So we need to retrieve the function from the function namespace -- which is the purpose of FUNCTION. Whenever we want to pass a function object, we need to get it from the function namespace.

For example in the case of a local function:

```
(flet ((my-and (x y) (and x y)))
  #'my-and)
```

LAMBDA as a convenience macro that expands into (FUNCTION (LAMBDA ...)) has been added during the design of Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'sharp-quote' symbol only with ordinary functions.

```
Note that only ordinary functions can be quoted with #’. It is an error to
quote a macro function or special function this way, or to quote a symbol with
#’ if that symbol does not name a function.

> #’if
Error: IF is not an ordinary function.
```

[COMMON LISP:
A Gentle Introduction
to Symbolic Computation, page 202](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf)