# Common LISP apply logic operator on list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one reduce a list of boolean values in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535236/how-does-one-reduce-a-list-of-boolean-values-in-common-lisp)

i have a list as follows: '(T Nil T T)

I want to apply the and-operator on that list. So that it only gives T when all entries in the list are T

I tried to apply #'and but it throws errors.

Comment: found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535236/how-does-one-reduce-a-list-of-boolean-values-in-common-lisp

Answer (score 4):

You can't apply [`and`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_and.htm) because it's not a function: it's a macro.

You want

```
(every #'identity list)
```

or

```
(loop for x in list always x)
```